# Change Label Font to Bold and Italic objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, fonts, ios8, uilabel

I have created a studio for user to create different type of logos. It also contains a couple of labels. I want to allow the user to convert those label font to bold and italic but I am having an issue that the fonts I am using dont have either Italic or Bold in their families. I tried a couple of solutions which contains:

```
UIFontDescriptor * fontD = [font.fontDescriptor
            fontDescriptorWithSymbolicTraits:UIFontDescriptorTraitBold];
selectedLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithDescriptor:fontD size:0];
```

but this changes my font to system font as no bold or italic font is found to it.

For Bold, I added some stroke so the font looks like bold which is ofcourse a bad practice but then again I got stuck for Italic. Is there any proper way that I can allow those fonts to be converted to Bold and Italic without having bold or italic in their family ?

Fonts I am using Aaargh, Average Sans, Cardinal, Comfortaa and others.

Comment: same problem happens, converts the font to system font @HariKrishnan.P

Comment: just as you said
   UIFontDescriptor *descriptor = [[UIFontDescriptor preferredFontDescriptorWithTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleHeadline] fontDescriptorWithSymbolicTraits:UIFontDescriptorTraitItalic];
    UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithDescriptor:descriptor size:descriptor.pointSize];
    selectedLabel.font = font;
@HariKrishnan.P

Comment: Yes it works on fonts whose family contains italic and bold but doesnt work on other fonts which dont have bold or italic in the family and thats what my problem is :( @HariKrishnan.P

Comment: You can't add (at least as built in) "fake bold" or "fake italic", like Photoshop would do. You maybe be able to do in in CoreText by doing it yourself.

Comment: Can your guide me towards that please ? @Larme

Comment: @AhsanEbrahim: I guess that you would have to understand how to bold, or how to make italic (which could be easier since it's a "simple" transformation for each characters), graphically speaking. Check info on CoreText, but that's clearly not easy.

Comment: @HariKrishnan.P thats the exact code that I tried initially and does not work.

Comment: @Larme i'll give it a try. Thank :)

Comment: I donot want to change the font, rather make the some font style change to bold or italic. @HariKrishnan.P